# Creating dashboard in ArcGIS Online with multiple selector possibilities

Tags: arcgis-pro, dashboard

I have not much experience creating dashboards, only the basics and I work in ArcGIS Online only. So maybe this is not even possible. I would like to create a dashboard with the following:

- Theme selector (population, poverty, ethnicity, disability)
- Region selector (8 regions)
- Zone selector (56 zones)

I have just one large database and one web map, containing several feature layers and of which I created several thematic maps depending on the theme.

I would like to be able to choose:
Select theme=population, Select zone=1 and this will show the thematic map for the population, who live in  zone 1. And I would like the possibility for the theme selector to be multiple so I can view like population combined with poverty.

I can choose the zone, but when I want to choose a thematic map by selecting e.g. population in the theme selector, it shows the thematic maps for both zone and region level.

When building such a dashboard in ArcGIS, how do I show only zone of zone is selected or region if region is selected?

The 'render only when filtered' option seems to not work in this case.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Asking if folks have experience and for generic suggestions are *off-topic* here. We are a *problem-solving site*, so you need to clearly state what you have tried, and where you are stuck. Please [Edit] the Question.